# How can I count words in complex documents (.rtf, .doc, .odt, etc)?

Tags: python, document, openoffice.org, word-count

I'm trying to write a Python function that, given the path to a document file, returns the number of words in that document. This is fairly easy to do with .txt files, and there are tools that allow me to hack support for a few more complex document formats together, but I want a really comprehensive solution.

Looking at OpenOffice.org's py-uno scripting interface and list of supported formats, it would seem ideal to load the documents in a headless OOo and call its word-count function. However, I can't find any py-uno tutorials or sample code that go beyond basic document generation, and even the code snippets I have found are out of date by a half-decade and no longer work.

Whether by using OOo and Uno or not, how can I get reliable word-counts for documents of various formats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**load the documents in a headless OOo**
 ***and call its [word-count function](http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/GenericTextDocument.html#WordCount)***

[PyODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter) is a recent (11-2009) script to use OOo to convert multiple file types. Looking at the script, it has basic loading of all the OOo supported documents.

This is how you start OOo as a headless service:

`soffice -headless -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard`

Then you just have to write a small bootstrapper that calls OOo on the commandline, runs your script, then closes OOo.

---

Comment: I'm not sure how I didn't find PyODConverter sooner. I had actually found artofsolving.com and downloaded some code from there, but wasn't able to make use of it; PyODConverter is, by contrast, very easy to read and use. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

This could be not the option for you, but in case it is - you can upload documents to Google Docs and then export in .txt format. Google usually does very nice job for the conversion.

You can find relevant APIs here: http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/documents/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html

Take a look at login, uploading and exporting sections.